# Web Scraping data from a confusing website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull data from this website: https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahan4dashboard/vahan/view/reportview.xhtml

I've used beautiful soup in the past for simple things like pulling the bestsellers list from Amazon so I'm a bit familiar with it but this website is very confusing and I'm looking for suggestions on how to get started here.

Essentially what I would like to loop through all the states in the 'State' filter and, for every state, I'd like to loop through every RTO in the 'RTO' filter. Based on this, I want to download the table data.

I know I've not added any code with this question - I need your help to understand how to get started doing this project since I got no idea how to navigate this website.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
This is how I'm getting the data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahan4dashboard/vahan/view/reportview.xhtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

This is me currently trying to find the relevant sections of the data but I'm lost here:

```
html = list(soup.children)[4]
list(html.children)
data = html.find_all('table')
print(data[0].prettify())
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks -- Saw your last sentence, but it would be cool if you would provide html, expected output, ... as text.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added in the code for me getting the data and how I'm trying to explore it currently

Comment: looks like its rendered through JS. There doesn't appear to be an api, so you'll need to use something like Selenium to iterate through those lists and pull the data.

Comment: you need send post request to that url & then you will get data